# null value for firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So basically, I can't display the collection on my html. I get a null value error for gamesList. But when I log it to the console, I can see the contents just fine, no problems there.

```
// get data
db.collection('games').get().then(snapshot => {
    setupGames(snapshot.docs);
});
```

```
// DOM elements
const gamesList = document.querySelector('.games');

// setup games
const setupGames = (data) => {

  let html = '';
  data.forEach(doc => {
    const game = doc.data();
    const li = `
      <li>
        <div class="collapsible-header grey lighten-4">${game.title}</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body white">${game.content}</div>
    
    `;

        html += li
        
  });

  gamesList.innerHTML = html;

}
```

So here something goes wrong and for the life of me I can't figure it out.

but when I use this the data does display correctly in the console, title and content:

```
// setup guides
const setupGames = (data) => {

  let html = '';
  data.forEach(doc => {
    const game = doc.data();
    console.log(game);
  });


}
```

Comment: Are you sure there's actually an element matched with a class of "games"?  Can you show the HTML for that?  What is the specific error, and what line is it referring to?  What is the log output that shows you actually have this element?

Comment: I seem to have fixed the problem by reading your comment. There was a bad reference in my html. Much appreciated to make me check that!

Answer (score 1):

I think, when you use get() function on a collection, it already returns you the document list, so you don't need to call **snapshot.docs**

There's an example here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection

If you want to use real time data with snapshots, try it this way:

```
db.collection('games').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
    setupGames(snapshot.docs);
});
```